# Interrupting watch if command execution was successful

Tags: bash, watch

I would like to be able to interrupt watch if execution of command was successful. In effect, I'm looking for a reverse behaviour than that offered via `--errexit`. As per man:

> `-e`, `--errexit`
>                 Freeze updates on command error, and exit after a key press.

## Example

The command:

```
ping -c 3 www.google.com
```

Fails due to the patchy connection*. I can re-run in the following manner to see when the connection is back:

```
watch -n 1 'ping -c 3 www.google.com'
```

I would like to stop watch if `ping` executes with no error.

---

** I'm not looking to find a better of way of verifying connectivity. The `ping` examples comes from using a mobile phone connection when on the train with mobile phone loosing signal every so often.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would start receiving pings once your network connection has been restored, start the `watch` after your connection has dropped and tell it to exit once the output changes:

```
watch -g -n 1 ping -c 3 www.google.com
```

As soon as you start receiving pongs, watch will exit.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution, you can invert the exit code of a command with [`!`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02):

```bash
# Never terminates
watch --errexit echo "test"

# Terminates on first invocation
watch --errexit ! echo "test"
```

This works in any POSIX shell, notably bash and zsh.